# c# to vb.net conversion - Action(Of T, string) as tuple item

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am trying to convert a tuple from c# to vb.net.  Here is the declaration of the tuple -

```
private List<Tuple<string, string, Action<T, string>>> items = new List<Tuple<string, string, Action<T, string>>>();
```

And I add items to Item3 (the Action) like this -

```
foreach(var iforeach(var i in items)
{
    i.Item3(t, string.Empty);
}
```

In vb.net, I define my tuple as follows -

```
Private list As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String, Action(Of T, String)))
```

And attempt to add an Action to Item3 like this -

```
Dim mytype = Activator.CreateInstance(Of T)
For Each item As Tuple(Of String, String, Action(Of T, String)) In list
    item.Item3(mytype, String.Empty)
Next
```

I've tried various iterations of different ways to add an Action to Item3, but nont seem to work.
For the example above, I get the following message in VS - Incorrect number of arguments in reference to ....

Can anyone shed some light on how this can be converted to vb.net?  Thanks.

Comment: What is `t` in your method?  VB.NET is not case-sensitive so it may be conflicting with the `T` generic parameter.

Comment: I changed t to mytype and still same results (Updated question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pull the action into a variable to invoke it:

```
For Each item As Tuple(Of String, String, Action(Of T, String)) In list
    Dim a as Action(Of T, String) = item.Item3
    a(t, String.Empty)
Next
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to use a separate variable - just use an explicit empty parenthesis pair to prevent the compiler from being confused (misinterpreting 'Item3' as a parameterized property, as Darryl noted):

```
For Each i In items
    i.Item3()(mytype, String.Empty)
Next i
```

Answer (score 3):

The VB compiler is interpreting the problematic line of code as a parameterized property.  There are two ways around it:

```
For Each item in list
    'option 1
    item.Item3.Invoke(mytype, String.Empty)

    'option 2
    Dim a = item.Item3
    a(mytype, String.Empty)
Next
```

Comment: Actually, 3 work-arounds (see my answer for the third option).